# MySQL: Update Record with only one FK record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.
Table A has the following:

```
UserID | ActiveFlag
000001 |    1
000002 |    1
000003 |    1
000004 |    1
```

Table B:

```
ID      | UserID    |   CustomerId
1       | 000001    |  10
2       | 000002    |  10
3       | 000002    |  11
4       | 000003    |  11
```

I want to update the `ActiveFlag` column in `Table A` to `0` where users in `table B` has a `CustomerID` of `10` and only `10`. Meaning that since, in the example, `UserID 000002` has two records in `Table B`: `CustomerID` `10` and `11`. I don't want to update `00002` in `table A`.

Answer (score 1):

10 and only 10

```
update table a set activeflag = o where a.userid in 
(
select b.userid from table b group by b.userid 
having min(b.customerid) = max(b.customerid) 
and min(b.customerid) = 10
)
```

Comment: `min(b.customerid) = max(b.customerid)` and min(b.customerid) = 10` is a better mechanism than using `count(distinct)`.  The latter is generally more expensive than other aggregation functions.

Comment: I'll try to remember that @GordonLinoff  I've changed it to be less expensive.  I'm was thinking readability  for answer count(distinct b.customerid) = 1

Answer (score 0):

`exists` comes to mind:

```
update tablea a
     set activeflag = 0
     where a.activeflag <> 0 and
           exists (select 1 from b where b.userid = a.userid and b.customerid = 10) and
           not exists (select 1 from b where b.userid = a.userid and b.customerid <> 10);
```

Comment: This doesn't exclude the users who have multiple customer IDs.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried this it affect 0 rows. Can you explain "select 1" please?

Comment: @slaskwroclaw18 . . . That is used with `exists`, which only counts rows, not columns.  "1" is easy to type.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET ActiveFlag = 0
WHERE UserID IN (
   SELECT UserID 
   FROM tableB 
   WHERE CustomerId = 10);
```

The principle is:

1. It filters out all `UserID` with `CustomerId` = 10 in Table B, i.e. 000001 (ID=1)    and 000002 (ID=2)
2. Check each `UserID`  from step 1, set `ActiveFlag = 0`. i.e. the first two rows in Table A are updated

Comment: Thank you, but would this not update UserID 00002 as well since they have a record in Table B with CustomerID 10? I do not want to update users with multiple CustomerIds even one of them happens to be 10.

Comment: Update only those with `CustomerID` = 10, not the one with `CustomerID` = 11

Comment: But some users have more than one customer ID. It's supposed to update only the users with just one customer ID that's = 10.

Comment: Sure but in table B two records have the same FK of 00002, one each with CustomerID 10 and 11 respectively. So since there is a record in table b with a FK of 00002 and CustomerId 11, UserID 000002 would still be update in table A.

Comment: This will not work.  In OP's example, this will also update UserID 000002.

Comment: Read the question carefully before comment.